# Is it possible to get an ISSN number for an online journal from an other country?

Tags: journals, legal-issues, online-publication

We are a group of international graduates in the process of launching an open access e-journal and we are now facing the different technical steps. Our based country has an ISSN national center, however we wonder if it is possible to get an ISSN from an other country (european or north american) even without being physically based there.

Thanks in advance for your answers

Comment: According to the Wiki page [How ISBNs are issued](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Book_Number):  ISBNs are issued by the ISBN registration agency that is responsible for that country or territory. I think you'll need to talk to the agency.

Comment: Just curious: why would you want to do that?

Comment: Are you sure there aren't already enough journals covering your field? There generally are more journals that one could wish for. Also, it sounds like you are trying to westernize your journal, possibly to increase its appeal. That sounds suspicious to me. Will your journal be pay for publish?

Answer (score 1):

Check the website/contact info with the specific agency, since I think this varies a lot. If I'm not mistaken, we got a Brazilian ISSN for a publication of papers resulting from the undegrad research program in my uni and it was all done by mail...

You can find the info for the agencies here http://www.issn.org/services/requesting-an-issn/